# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException with toplink and JPA

Tags: sql, jpa

I've a problem with JPA, whenever execute this query

```
@NamedQuery(name = "Usuario.getUsuarioIntento", query = "SELECT  u.intentos_id FROM Usuario u WHERE u.username = :username and u.borrado = 0")
```

i get this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: NamedQuery of name: Usuario.getUsuarioIntento not found.
```

But if i execute this query

```
@NamedQuery(name = "Usuario.getUsuarioIntento", query = "SELECT  u.id FROM Usuario u WHERE u.username = :username and u.borrado = 0")
```

Work fine,Why?

My table,Usuario:

[MY USER TABLE](http://i48.tinypic.com/4kxj03.png)

i try with other column as  'superusuario','version_jpa' and doesn't work, the only columns that work fine are 'id,'borrado' and 'username'

Class Usuario:

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date                fechaCreacion;

@Id
@GeneratedValue (strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private int                 id;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Password            password;

@OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<Password>      clavesAntiguas;

@OneToOne
private Persona             persona;

private String              sessionId;

private String              username;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH)
private Rol                 rol;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH)
private Perfil              perfil;

@OneToOne (cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private IntentosBloqueo     intentos;

private boolean             superUsuario;

private int                 borrado;
private int                 esManager;

@OneToMany ( cascade = {CascadeType.ALL} , fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Collection<UsuarioSociedad> sociedades; 

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH)
  @JoinTable (name="USR_UND_VIS",
  joinColumns={
   @JoinColumn (name="ID_USU", table="USUARIO", referencedColumnName="ID"),
  },
  inverseJoinColumns= 
   @JoinColumn (name="ID_UNI", table="UND_ORG", referencedColumnName="ID")
  )
  private List<UnidadOrganizativa> unidadesVisibles;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH)
  @JoinTable (name="USR_UND_DIS",
  joinColumns={
   @JoinColumn (name="ID_USU", table="USUARIO", referencedColumnName="ID"),
  },
  inverseJoinColumns= 
   @JoinColumn (name="ID_UNI", table="UND_ORG", referencedColumnName="ID")
  )
  private List<UnidadOrganizativa> unidadesDisponibles;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because Named query works on Entity objetc not on datbase column. You try to find another entity object which contains that id. In That case your named query will give  you the object of that entity class and from that object u can get the id or whtever fiels of that entity.

JPA named query is not like SQL or oracle query.

Iin in DB your column name is xyz but in entity your column name is ABC then you have to fetch  ABC in named query not XYZ.